# Write a program Function should be able to remove all the vowels from both the strings and concatenate them together using C?

Tags: c, string

*Write a program which has a function to which we pass two strings represented as pointers.
The function should be able to remove all the vowels from both the strings and concatenate them together.
Sample Input :
First String : "abdef"
Second String : "ghijk"*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJey0.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void filter (char *p, char *q)
{
  while (*p != '\0')
    {
      if (*p != 'a' || *p != 'e' || *p != 'i' || *p != 'o' || *p != 'u')
    {
      *q = *p;
      q++;
    }
      p++;
    }
  *q = '\0';
}

int main ()
{
  char str1[10] = "hello";
  char str2[10];
  char *p, *q;
  p = &str1[0];
  q = &str2[0];
  filter (p, q);
  printf ("%s", str2);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample Output :
"bdfghjk"

But the program copies all characters from the original string. Why?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?  Most questions on Stack Overflow should come with a little bit of code (like a [mcve]) and a clear description of how the code isn't working.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

    void filter (char *p, char *q)
    {
      while (*p != '\0')
        {
          if (*p != 'a' || *p != 'e' || *p != 'i' || *p != 'o' || *p != 'u')
        {
          *q = *p;
          q++;
        }
          p++;
        }
      *q = '\0';
    }

    int main ()
    {
      char str1[10] = "hello";
      char str2[10];
      char *p, *q;
      p = &str1[0];
      q = &str2[0];
      filter (p, q);
      printf ("%s", str2);
      return 0;
    }

Comment: @TauseefFeraz [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72848892/edit) your question and put the code in there. Also include an actual question.

Comment: I'm glad to see you have some code.  Please edit your question to include that code, format and indent it properly, and also tell us why you think it isn't working.  Your question should say what output the code gives and what output you expected.

Comment: Take the [tour] read [ask], read [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812) and [How much research is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), what is a [mcve]. When you have a *specific* problem, come back and ask again.

Comment: This (attempts to) make a copy of a string with the vowels removed, but it is not the whole programme from the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You've simply used the wrong logical operator, `||`.

That makes it copy `*p` if it's not `a` **or** not `e` etc. That expression will always be `true`.

You need `&&` to copy it only if it's not `a` **and** not `e` etc., so you need the `&&` operator:

```
void filter(char *p, char *q) {
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p != 'a' && *p != 'e' && *p != 'i' && *p != 'o' && *p != 'u') {
            *q = *p;
            q++;
        }
        p++;
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```